# How to handle conditional query manipulation in Symfony 2 repositories?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dry

My application needs to manipulate a query conditionally. To elaborate; a query's result set needs to be restricted if the currently logged in user is **not** an admin.

I really don't like how much I'm currently repeating myself, I already know it's a bad way of doing it, but here goes:

An example from one of my controllers:

```
try {
    if ($sc->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $gallery = $gr->findById($id); // If the user is an admin, show all
    } else {
        $gallery = $gr->findActiveById($id); // Otherwise, show only active ones
    }
} catch (NoResultException $e) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('That gallery doesn\'t exist!');
}
```

You can probably guess already what's going on here in that `$gr` which is the repository. Here are the 2 methods in question from said repository:

```
public function findById($id)
{
    $dql = '
        SELECT
            g,
            gci,
            gi,
            t,
            gv
        FROM
            DWIPortfolioBundle:Gallery AS g
        LEFT JOIN
            g.coverImage AS gci
        LEFT JOIN
            g.images AS gi
        LEFT JOIN
            g.tags AS t
        LEFT JOIN
            g.views AS gv
        WHERE
            g.id = :id';

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $query->useResultCache(true)
        ->getSingleResult();
}

public function findActiveById($id)
{
    $dql = '
        SELECT
            g,
            gci,
            gi,
            t,
            gv
        FROM
            DWIPortfolioBundle:Gallery AS g
        LEFT JOIN
            g.coverImage AS gci
        LEFT JOIN
            g.images AS gi
        LEFT JOIN
            g.tags AS t
        LEFT JOIN
            g.views AS gv
        WHERE
            g.id = :id
        AND
            g.isActive = 1';
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   // This last 'AND' bit is the only part that is 
   // different from the method above this

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)
        ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $query->useResultCache(true)
        ->getSingleResult();
}
```

So, my question is, how should I go about making this DRY? I know that I shouldn't inject the user, the security context or any of that sort of thing because this repository should only be concerned with itself. But I'm struggling to think of the best way to handle manipulating the queries (I'm not against using the QueryBuilder if that is needed to make this structured a little better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second parameter and use `QueryBuilder` in your `findById` method.

```
public function findById($id, $is_active=false) {
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select("g, gci, gi, t, gv")
            ->from("DWIPortfolioBundle:Gallery", "g")
            ->leftJoin('g.coverImage', 'gi')
            // ....
            ->where('g.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id);
    if ($is_active) {
        $query->andWhere('g.isActive = 1');
    }

    return $query->getQuery()->useResultCache(true)->getSingleResult();

}
```

I guess more DRY-way would be to have a single function which retrieves many possible ways of showing galleries, using some sort of `$options` array:

```
public function getGallery($options) {
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select("g")
        ->from("DWIPortfolioBundle:Gallery", "g");

    if ($options) {
        if (isset($options['id'])) {
            $query->andWhere('g.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $options['id']);
        }

        if (isset($options['is_active'])) {
            $query->andWhere('g.isActive = :is_active')->setParameter('is_active', $options['is_active']);
        }

        if (isset($options['limit'])) {
            $query->setMaxResults($options['limit']);
        }

        // Any other filtering options you might need 
    }

    return $query->getQuery()->useResultCache(true)->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I like the second approach as I've done something similar before, and it can be a little more obvious to see what's happening in some ways. Though for this particular problem I may end up going for the first option, since the task at hand is fairly simple. I'll probably be using that second method in the future.

Comment: QueryBuilder is a great tool for your case. Its possible to build some really complex and flexible filtering/paginating/ordering functions with it.

Comment: Also, do you need that many joins? You could use default repository `findBy` methods, `->findBy(array(id => $id, 'isActive' => true))`, as depicted [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Comment: It seems that if I remove the joins the other entities aren't cached and so it queries the database instead of memcache for them every time. Is there a different way around this? Also, the findBy method won't cache things on it's own either will it?

Comment: AFAIK, no. If you fetch just one entity from the database, then for getting the related entities, doctrine will issue a query. So probably joins are welcome here. Not sure about findBy caching, but I'm guessing it wont. Would be nice to test that anyway.